# Why does "(" cause a regex not to match?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
var foo = "{(y-7)}({x + d})"
var find = "{(y-7)}";
var replacement = "12";
var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
foo = foo.replace(re, replacement);
```

But this results in the exact same string, without any changes.
But, if I remove the parens i.e "(" and ")" from the expression, then it seems to work. Why

Why won't it match when the expressions contain "("?

Comment: parenthesis are special characters used for grouping, to have a literal parenthese you need to escape it.

Answer (score 4):

You have to escape `(` and `)` since they have [special meaning in regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
var find = "\\{\\(y-7\\)\\}"
```

Same stands for [`{` and `}`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html).

This escaping only needs to happen in regexes (i.e. your `find`), `foo` is fine as is since that's just an ordinary string.

I suggest you use JavaScript's built in functionality to have less escaping:

```
var re = /\{\(y-7\)\}/g;
```

## Update

> The string is handed to me like that, so I need to do a replace

```
var find = "{(y-7)}";
find = find.replace("\\", "\\\\")
           .replace("(", "\\(").replace(")", "\\)")
           .replace("{", "\\{").replace("}", "\\}");
```

I call this "escaping hell", but generating a regex is not trivial, though you may get lucky.
I suggest you learn to use it first and then try to generate it.

Comment: My strings "find" etc are created programmatically. How can I escape the "{" and "(" then. Can you explain ?

Comment: If even the `find` is generated, then you must have a code like this: `find = "(" + somevar + ")"`, escape (put backslash before) the `(){}` there.

Comment: I can't do that. The string is handed to me like that, so I need to do a replace.

Comment: curly brackets are indeed special characters but most of the time (when they are not around an integer or two integers separated by comma) you don't need to escape them.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte better safe than sorry :)

Comment: I still don't understand how to escape the "{" and "(" if they are already in the string. It seems like a recursive problem. If I new how to escape it, then I could escape it! XD

Comment: @John in other languages, it could be possible through `\Q\E` block. .  But js won't support this feature..

Answer (score 4):

Characters that have a special meaning in a regular expression needs to be escaped. You escape them by putting a backslash in front of them, and to put a backslash in a string you need to escape that by putting a backslash in front of it:

```
var find = "\\{\\(y-7\\)\\}";
```

(In some situations characters doesn't need escaping in a regular expression, because it can be understood without it, but start by escaping all characters that have a special meaning, then you can read up on the exact situations where it is not needed.)

Demo:

```js
var foo = "{(y-7)}({x + d})"
var find = "\\{\\(y-7\\)\\}";
var replacement = "12";
var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
foo = foo.replace(re, replacement);

// show result in StackOverflow snippet
document.write(foo);
```

Comment: "find" is created programmatically. How can I escape the "{" then ?

Comment: @John: You can escape the characters using `find = find.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");`. Found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript/494122#494122